# Why cannot discover user in Airdrop when open personal hotspot?

Tags: ios, airdrop

When my iPhone opens the personal hotspot, I cannot find other users via Airdrop. What is the theory behind it?

Answer (score -1):

AirDrop is different than a personal hotspot.

A personal hotspot is for sharing your internet connection.

AirDrop has separate controls, located in the control center.   You must also turn on Bluetooth and wifi.

[Official Apple doc with screenshots.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144)